# Dimension of $S_{\lambda}V$ for a column $\lambda$

Tags: abstract-algebra, representation-theory

Assume we are given an $n$-dimensional vector space with basis $\{e_i\}$, the Young diagram $\lambda$ for the partition $1+1+...+1=n$ and the corresponding Young symmetrizer $c_{\lambda}$. Further let $\hat{c}_{\lambda}$ be the scalar multiple of $c_{\lambda}$ such that $\hat{c}_{\lambda}$ is idempotent.

I want to see that $V^{\otimes n}.\hat{c}_{\lambda}$ is $1$-dimensional.

As far as I know: $S_{\lambda}V:=V^{\otimes n}.c_{\lambda}=V^{\otimes n}.\hat{c}_{\lambda}$. But for our choice of $\lambda$ the first tern is equal to $\text{Alt}^n(V)=\text{span}\{\sum\text{sgn}(\sigma)v_{\sigma 1}\otimes ...\otimes v_{\sigma n}, v_i\in V\}$.

So why does this space has dimension $1$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $v_1\wedge v_2\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n=\sum_{\sigma\in S_n}\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)v_{\sigma(1)}\otimes v_{\sigma(2)}\otimes \cdots v_{\sigma(n)}.$ Note that 
$$v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_i\wedge\cdots\wedge v_j\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n=-v_1\wedge\cdots\wedge v_j\wedge\cdots\wedge v_i\wedge\cdots\wedge v_n$$
since $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma\tau)=-\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$ when $\tau=(i\,j)$. It follows that, if $v_i=v_j$, then the element above is $0$.

Next, observe that the multi-linearity of the tensor product implies that any element of $\mathrm{Alt}^n(V)$ can be expressed as a linear combination of elements of the form
$e_{i_1}\wedge\cdots\wedge e_{i_n}$, where $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is a basis for $V$. By the previous paragraph, all the $e_{i_j}$ must be distinct for such an element to be distinct. This forces $\mathrm{Alt}^n(V)$ to be $1$-dimensional with basis $e_1\wedge\cdots\wedge e_n$.

Comment: Got it, thank you! So the basis vector, using the other notation, is $(e_1\otimes ...\otimes e_n).\hat{c}_{\lambda}$. Is there a general form for $(e_{i_1}\otimes ...\otimes e_{i_n}).\hat{c}_{\lambda}$ in terms of the basis vector?

Comment: $(e_{i_1}\otimes\cdots e_{i_n}).\hat{c_\lambda}=\pm(e_{1}\otimes\cdots e_{n}).\hat{c_\lambda}$ (assuming it's nonzero). Use the alternating condition to rearrange the indices in increasing order (e.g. $e_2\wedge e_1=-e_1\wedge e_2$).

Comment: Makes sense, yes. Can we say whether it is positive or negative? Is it the sign of the corresponding permutation?

Comment: In any given case, yes. if $\sigma(k)=i_k$ for each $k$, then the sign is $\mathrm{sgn}(\sigma)$.

Comment: Yep, thats what I've edited! Thank you. I can't vote up since I have no reputation, sorry! One other question: If I change my Young diagram to the partition $k+...+k$ of $nk$, is there an easy form of $S_{\lambda}V$?

Comment: That question is more difficult. I would look up "rectangular partition"

Comment: http://front.math.ucdavis.edu/0109.5093

Comment: Well I want the following: I want to show that the $1$ dim. $\text{GL}(V)$ representation $F\mapsto (\det F)^k$ is iso to $S_{\lambda}(V)$ hence I have to come up with a $\lambda$ and I guess that this is $k+...+k=nk$ as above. That is the reason of my question.

Comment: Actually I don’t see how your linked paper helps in understanding this case

Comment: Why can we be sure, that $e_1\wedge ...\wedge e_n$ is not zero?

Comment: because $\sigma(i)=i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$ if, and only if, $\sigma=id$.

Comment: I understand the 'iff' but I understand not why this shows that the element is not zero.